# for_each print data not correct

Tags: c++, opencl

I am now learning OpenCL, and I am trying to write a "hello world" example; I create platform, device, and context.

Now I want to get device information from the device so that I create and save information in a vector then print them. For this I am using `clGetDeviceInfo`.

The problem is that the return information from the call are in a different format , so I trying to write a print function to print data, but I have a problem when I use `for_each` to print data. I can' print most of data because I can pass only one type data into print function, and the print function prints the data in that same type only. The remaining data prints incorrectly.

the return data for `clGetDeviceInfo`
http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html

```
template <typename t >
void print (void *data )
{   

    boost::any _t = static_cast<t> (data);
    cout << boost::any_cast<t> (_t) << endl << endl;
}

cl_device_info devinfo_list[] = 
{
CL_DEVICE_TYPE , 
CL_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID ,
CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS ,
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS ,
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES ,
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE ,
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_CHAR ,
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_SHORT,
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_INT ,
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_LONG,
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT,
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_DOUBLE,
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_HALF,
CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_CHAR ,
CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_SHORT,
CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_INT,
CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_LONG,
CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT,
CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_DOUBLE,
CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_HALF,
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY ,
CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS ,
CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE ,
CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT ,
CL_DEVICE_MAX_READ_IMAGE_ARGS ,
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WRITE_IMAGE_ARGS ,
CL_DEVICE_IMAGE2D_MAX_WIDTH ,
CL_DEVICE_IMAGE2D_MAX_HEIGHT ,
CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_WIDTH ,
CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_HEIGHT,
CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_DEPTH ,
CL_DEVICE_MAX_SAMPLERS ,
CL_DEVICE_MAX_PARAMETER_SIZE ,
CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN ,
CL_DEVICE_MIN_DATA_TYPE_ALIGN_SIZE ,
CL_DEVICE_SINGLE_FP_CONFIG ,
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHE_TYPE ,
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHELINE_SIZE ,
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHE_SIZE ,
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE ,
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE ,
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_ARGS,
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE ,
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE ,                    
CL_DEVICE_ERROR_CORRECTION_SUPPORT ,         
CL_DEVICE_PROFILING_TIMER_RESOLUTION  ,      
CL_DEVICE_ENDIAN_LITTLE ,                    
CL_DEVICE_AVAILABLE,                         
CL_DEVICE_COMPILER_AVAILABLE,         
CL_DEVICE_EXECUTION_CAPABILITIES ,           
CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES   ,               
CL_DEVICE_NAME   ,                           
CL_DEVICE_VENDOR  ,                          
CL_DRIVER_VERSION ,                          
CL_DEVICE_PROFILE  ,                         
CL_DEVICE_VERSION  ,                         
CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS ,                       
CL_DEVICE_PLATFORM  ,                        


};

vector<void*> _data;

size_t h = NULL ;
    for ( unsigned int infos = 0 ; infos<ARRAYSIZE(devinfo_list) ; infos++)
{
    err = ::clGetDeviceInfo ( devices[0] ,devinfo_list[infos] ,NULL, NULL ,&h);
    if ( err == 0 )
    {
        _data.resize ( _data.size() + 1 );
        _data.at(_data.size() - 1) = alloca(h);
    }

    err = ::clGetDeviceInfo ( devices[0] ,devinfo_list[infos], h ,_data.at(_data.size() - 1),NULL);


}

for_each ( _data.begin() , _data.end() , print<char*>); // the data from char* only print crrectly
```

Comment: you expected X, but you got Y. so what are X and Y for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the documentation and that function returns the result inside a `void*` and you must cast it to whatever type you were expecting. I also see they have a list of types returned by the different parameters.

I would solve this in the way that I would not only have a list of the `cl_device_info` but also store what types they return, then use that info to do the cast. If you do it with a struct or 2-dimensional array that is up to you.

Comment: thank you . your idea is exactly mine , and i put this solution at bottom of the list because it's impractical specially when you have a list of 50 different information type ,

Comment: Yes, well the void* is opaque and you have no idea what is hiding behind it so its pretty much the only solution I have right now.